# После того как я заработал 383 единицы репутации перестали отображаться репутация и знаки многих пользователей почему?

Tags: поддержка, репутация

После того как я заработал 383 единицы репутации перестали отображаться репутация и знаки многих пользователей около вопросов и ответов(в том числе и моя).
Отображается только у пользователей с очень большой.

Почему?

Comment: Опс сейчас уже отображаются...Спасибо!